# How to upload multiple files using Sharepoint API with Javascript code

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, file-upload, office365apis, subfolders

I have a script to upload single file with file name specified to sharepoint, I am looking how can we upload all the files that listed in a folder to sharepoint.

Uploading single file

```
var filepath = C:\\Documents\\Files\\file.txt;
var url = <sharepointurl>/file.txt;
var accessToken = "<token>";

//These are getting main url and relative url for the site
var filename = url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
var url = url.replace(filename,'');

var mainUrl = url.substring(0,nthIndex(url, "/", 2))
var relativeUrl = url.substring(url.indexOf("sites/"));

try {
        postFile(mainUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/" + relativeUrl + "')/Files/add(url='" +   filename + "',overwrite=true)",filepath,accessToken,false);
        
    }
    catch(err) {
        
    }
function postFile(url, fileName, accessToken, async) {
 
        // Prepare post data
        var stream = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
        stream.Type = 1;
        stream.Open()
    
        // Begin File Upload
        stream.Write(readBinaryFile(fileName));
        
        // Finish Upload Content
        stream.Position = 0;
        
        // post request
        var xhr = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xhr.Open("POST", url, async);
        xhr.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        xhr.Send(stream.Read());
        resultVar = xhr.responseText;
}

function nthIndex(str, pat, n){
    var L= str.length, i= -1;
    while(n-- && i++<L){
        i= str.indexOf(pat, i);
        if (i < 0) break;
    }
    return i;
}

function readBinaryFile(fileName) {
    var stream = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
    stream.Type = 1;
    stream.Open();
    stream.LoadFromFile(fileName);
    return stream.Read();
}
```

So in the above code I am giving the full path(C:\Documents\Files\file.txt) to upload the file to sharepoint. Here I am looking if I give folderpath like "C:\Documents\Files\" and I need to upload all the files present in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function upload() {
    // Define the folder path for this example.
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/sites/dev/SiteAssets';

    // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
    var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
    //var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();
    var fileCount = fileInput[0].files.length;
    // Get the server URL.
    var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var filesUploaded = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++){
        // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        var getFile = getFileBuffer(i);
        getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer,i) {

            // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
            var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer,i);
            addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {
                //$("#msg").append("<div>File : "+file.d.Name+" ... uploaded sucessfully</div>");
                filesUploaded++;
                if(fileCount == filesUploaded){
                    alert("All files uploaded successfully");
                    //$("#msg").append("<div>All files uploaded successfully</div>");
                    $("#getFile").value = null;
                    filesUploaded = 0;
                }
            });
            addFile.fail(onError);
        });
        getFile.fail(onError);

    }

    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    function getFileBuffer(i) {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result,i);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[i]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer,i) {
    var index = i;

        // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
        var fileName = fileInput[0].files[index].name;

        // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        });
    }
}

// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
}
</script>
<input type="file" id="getFile" multiple>
<input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="upload()">
```

Source:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/006a1b18-0402-4c5b-a579-b6a01fe75ab3/multiple-attachment-upload-in-sharepoint-document-library-using-rest-apisp-services-or-jsom-working?forum=sharepointgeneral